# How to debug throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms on Smallrye Reactive Messaging?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

So we see this message in the logs...

```
The record 183504174 from topic-partition 'xxxxxx-11' has waited for 60 seconds to be acknowledged. ... The last committed offset for this partition was 183504173
```

That `183504174` is the actual record not the offset right?

So if the last offset was `183504173` do we just go to the offset `183504174` at 'xxxxxx-11' partition 11 and that's the faulty message?

Comment: It is the offset, and yes, it looks like you have a poison pill (a message that cannot be processed successfully).

Comment: In addition to that, you can activate debug logging on Kafka connector with `quarkus.log.category."io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka".level=DEBUG`. It'll log offset commits and actions on rebalance, it can help you understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @Clement there no poison pill that we can tell. We have `@Incoming` and `@Outgoing` and `POST_PROCESSING` We don't care for the chain, all we want is that `@Outgoing` writes to the topic. The downstream consumer/processor will handle it on its own time. So we switched to `PRE_PROCESSING` and voila errors gone. Also we could not reproduce the error using the record at offset `183504174`  partition `xxxxxx-11` we have plenty of validation. It would be nice that throttled.max-age.ms errors get pushed to a DLQ as part of the DLQ strategy.